# How do I find the name of the asset to add to Bowerfile

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, bower

Sorry this is a super noob Bower question, but Google is really not turning anything up here.

**How do I know the name of the library to include in my Bowerfile?**

For example:

- I want AngularJS. So I add `asset 'angular'` to my Bowerfile because I read it in a tutorial.
- Now I want to add D3js.  I found this bower.json in D3's github repo: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/bower.json. Since its name is 'd3', does that mean I just add `asset 'd3'` to my bowerfile?

Is there some public site like that lists all the Bower components? For example with Ruby Gems there is RubyGems.org. For PHP's composer there is https://packagist.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of package names ( the things you should include) here:

http://bower.io/search/

Also, yes, the 'name' attribute of the bower.json in some official repository whose code you want will match the asset you need to install.

The bower command line tool also has a search feature that will help you. Read this:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-bower

Hope that helps. Post your bower.json up and what commands you are trying if it doesn't seem right.